# Elegantly Handling large MySQL rows to be processed by PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So, i'd been exposed to more and more real life application where:
`SELECT * FROM table` is too heavy already, resulting to
`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 47 bytes) in`.

What I am currently doing is splitting these mySQL rows into `batches`, setting a variable `$perPage`, then passing a `$_GET['page']` variable to the page, something link: `process.php?page=1`

Which I think is "good". But sometimes, we want full automation. So I set `$nextPage = (int) $_GET['page'] + 1`, then redirect the page to then iteration after processing these mySQL rows
`header("Location: process.php?p="$nextPage)`

Now, this would give you some issues:

1. Its harder to debug. If a warning/notice issued in page 3, you won't be able to see these output not unless you log them or looked at your php logs.
2. Browsers won't allow you to redirect too much. So, we either use command-line curl or code another php script that will cURL `process.php` with follow-redirect enabled.

This is how I currently handle this, but sometimes thinking that I need to code more just to make it work is a bit frustrating. **Does anyone know how to handle these more elegantly?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PHP Generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) are ideal for this type of scenario.

> A generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over
>   a set of data without needing to build an array in memory, which may
>   cause you to exceed a memory limit, or require a considerable amount
>   of processing time to generate. Instead, you can write a generator
>   function, which is the same as a normal function, except that instead
>   of returning once, a generator can yield as many times as it needs to
>   in order to provide the values to be iterated over.

You shouldn't be storing all the data to memory but instead process records by chunks.

Using `yield`(from `C`) will allow you to achieve that.

Forget about the redirect thing, this sound like it should be a `CLI` script anyway.

Here is an example on how to implement it:

```
function getRecords()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT field1, field2 FROM table';
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        yield $row;
    }
}

foreach ($this->getRecords() as $record) {
    //process then release, do not store
}
```

Notice:

1. I select specific fields, since memory is a concern you should be careful with everything, `SELECT *` can unnecessarily make you run out of memory.
2. Something like `fetchAll()` would not work, because it will get all the rows at once.
3. Do not store the data in memory when iterating in the `foreach` this defeats the purpose of generators.

Comment: You are a PRO. apparently, that's all what it takes!

Answer (score 0):

In a loop; get a piece of data from database do whatever you want, free memory with [unset()](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.unset.php) function and then get next piece of data.